# Проблема с кодировкой при использовании .format()

Tags: python, python-2.x

При попытке вывести результат с помощью

```
print 'Совпадений нет - {}'.format(a)
```

появляется

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0410' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

если использовать

```
print "Совпадений нет", a
```

то все отрабатывает норм

Как правильно пофиксить эту проблему ? и почему первый вариант выдаёт ошибку а второй нет

Comment: В начале файла укажите `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` И возможно нужно нужно добавлять префикс `u` к строке, т.е. `u'Совпадений нет - {}'`

Comment: @DmitryD почему вы отклонили мою правку? она же быда верной

Comment: @gil9red Помогло, еще вопрос: пытаюсь вместо `print` использовать запись в txt файл: `f.write u'Совпадений нет - {}'.format(a)` и выдаёт ту же ошибку. В чем может быть проблема

Comment: `print` это оператор, поэтому без скобок можно писать (кст, в питоне 3 это уже функцию), а `f.write` функция, тут нужны скобки. Странно, что выдает такую же ошибку, а не ошибку синтаксиса...

Answer (score 0):

Для корректного вывода в shell или записи в файл мне помогло:

```
'Совпадений нет - {}'.format(a.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))+'\n'
```